# How to execute prepare statement using if statement in PHP PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I am fetching some data from MySQL database using PHP PDO prepared statement. I have to use if statement inside the execution of the prepared statement. See my codes below for better understanding

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE 1=1";

if(isset($_GET['one'])){
    $query .= " AND one = :one";
}

if(isset($_GET['two'])){
    $query .= " AND two = :two";
}

if(isset($_GET['three'])){
    $query .= " AND three = :three";
}

$result = $db->prepare($query);
$result->execute([

    /* ------------------------------------
    How to declare the above parameters here
    as it will show error if any of the if statement is not true? 
    ----------------------------------------*/

]);
```

I want to know how to declare the prepared array parameter using if statement inside the `$result->execute(......])` block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an empty `$params` array, and inside each `if` block you can push the appropriate value to it. For example:

```
if(isset($_GET['one'])){
    $query .= " AND one = :one";
    $params[':one'] = $_GET['one'];
}
```

Then you can simply do

```
$result->execute($params);
```

Note that you can based on what you've written, you could simplify your code with an outer `foreach` on a list of parameter names e.g.

```
$names= array('one', 'two', 'three');
$params = array();
foreach ($names as $name) {
    if (isset($_GET[$name])) {
         $query .= " AND $name = :$name";
         $params[":$name"] = $_GET[$name];
    }
}
$result->execute($params);
```